# Firefox doesn't work

Tags: firefox

TOday I came to job to find out that firefox doesn't working.

Particularly: I am able to open it, but when I enter some web addres and hit enter or open any bookmark, I am no redirected to desired page. Meaning browser doesn't reacts any how on my actions.

What might be the problem?

FF is 9.0.1 and OS is MacOS Lion

**UPDATE 1**
Yes, I am able to open html files.

Comment: The first thing I would try is re-installing Firefox. It should not alter your profile. If your profile is the problem, then we can try removing it or creating a new one.

Comment: Have set proxy settings? Can you check it? ALso you can try to load Firefox with no addons (run in safe mode). Also you can try to create a new profile

Comment: Can you open HTML files on your computer with Firefox?

Comment: Did you try restarting FF?  Don't just kill the window, but click on Firefox on the top bar and click "exit".

Comment: Currently I will reinstall it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to do: restart your computer. If that does not help, reinstall firefox. If that does not help, save your profile (bookmarks, etc.) and completely remove firefox (including all related files) and reinstall it.